# Get tar to exclude some files

Tags: tar

I want to make a backup, but my tapes don't have space for everything, so I decided to not back up virtual machines (over 1tb).

I have the virtual machines in `.local/share/libvirt/images`

I used this command

```
tar cvf - /home/user -X altro/file.esclude  | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt  -k "password" | dd bs=80M of=/dev/st0
```

In `altro/file.esclude` I put this line `/home/user/.local/share/libvirt/images`

But tar ignore the exclude file and backups everything!!

So I use

```
tar cvf - /home/user --exclude '/home/user/.local/share/libvirt/images'  | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt  -k "password" | dd bs=80M of=/dev/st0
```

And...
same thing!

Why?

---

System is Slackware 14.2 with gnu tar

Comment: Does it work if you remove `/home/user/`? (See also [a related question in askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/811081/how-do-i-use-tar-to-exclude-all-files-of-a-certain-directory).)

Comment: Also, I believe the syntax is `--exclude='pattern'` (an equal sign, not a space). And, just in case, provide some information about which version of `tar` is this. GNU?

Comment: yes gnu tar on linux,i add now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X must be before the paths to include in the tar file.

So:

```
tar cvf - /home/user -X altro/file.esclude  | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt  -k "password" | dd bs=80M of=/dev/st0
```

is WRONG.

This:

```
tar cvf - -X /home/user/altro/file.esclude /home/user | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt  -k "pass" | dd bs=80M of=/dev/st0
```

is RIGHT

In the exclude file, I use

```
/home/user/.local/share/libvirt/images/*
```